# Copying a files data to creat a copy

Tags: python, encryption, jpeg

I want to test an encryption method based on hex form of files. With the following code:

```
import binascii
filename = 'file'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
#content=binascii.hexlify(content)
file = open('file2', 'w+')
file.write(content)
```

Trying to make copies of files by copying their data to the new file. It has worked for files with text, pdf and similar formats even mp4 but for jpg I get this:

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x66 0x66)
```

I don't know why it should happen.

Comment: maybe open it with "wb" instead of "w+"

Comment: TNX :). it worked but why?

Comment: because its binary data so you must open as binary ("b") ... "+" means write and read... but you reall just want write ... but its binary data

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to create a copy of the file? if yes, I'd rather do:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('file', 'file2')
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity  ... although I doubt its as simple as that in the end :P

Comment: No...I want to modify hex code of them and copying is just a test to see if I could create a new encrypted file or not.

Comment: Sorry Parisa, I didn't have enough info on the context to help. still not sure about what you want here, good luck anyway :-)